# Python websocket - How to let some data flow?

Tags: python, api, websocket, stream

I'm new to the platform, this is my first message and I need your help.

I'm working on a school project where I have to analyze data. I chose to analyze the Binance stream, especially the trades. I had no problem using their web socket, I get lines.

The problem is that I get a lot of lines. For 1 second for example I can recover 10, 15 lines or much more.

I would like to recover 1 line per second for example.

I tried to put a time.sleep(1) but it doesn't work. It just "pauses" the stream but resumes at the line where it stopped. I want to avoid processing some lines, that's why I would like to get 1 line per second.

I use this library
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html

```
def handle_message(msg): 

if msg['e'] == 'error':
    print(msg['m'])
else:
    bitcoins_exchanged = float(msg['p']) * float(msg['q'])
    timestamp = msg['T'] / 1000
    timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print("{} - {} - Price: {}".format(timestamp,msg['s'],msg['p']))



conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket(BTCUSDT, handle_message)
bm.start()
```

Thanks for your help. For information, I use Python 2.7.

Comment: Perhaps add a pseudo-code (example) to help others see how your code is shaped. Welcome to SO! (:

Comment: Kindly upload the snippet of your code

Comment: Hi I just updated my message with my code.

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidHaris you have an idea ?